# SPARQL delete if exists

Tags: sparql

Let's assume the following Graph as an turtle file:

```
pf:A a CLASSA 
  rdfs:label "a"

pf:B a CLASSB
  rdfs:label "b"
  pf:has A
```

My Goal is an query to delete A, and **if** B exists also B.

The current Query expects A and B to exist, if A exists without B nothing is deleted as the query is not satisfied.

```
DELETE {
    ?A ?p ?o .
    ?B ?p ?o .
 }
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o
    {
        SELECT ?b WHERE
        {
             ?b a CLASSB .
             ?b pf:has A;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question: Is there an way SPARQL offers me to ask for the existence of B and if it exists to also delete it?

If I wrap it in OPTIONAL {} it deletes all instances of CLASSB from the turtle file.

Comment: I think I don't get the question - what do you mean "if B exist" - what is the existence of B? Also, DELETE will always only delete statements, that exists, so your question is currently about vague. Note, RDF is made of triples, saying "delete B" is misleading or not technical enough. If you would say delete all triples where the resource `pf:B` is the subject, ok - but then I don't get why you restrict it to "if exists" instead of saying "just delete all (outgoing?) triples about B"

Comment: you current DELETE statement indeed doesn't work, neither variable `?A` nor `?B` are bound to anything, so what do you expect to happen then? Please understand that the bindings of the `DELETE` clause will be computed in the `WHERE` part

Comment: @UninformedUser The SPARQL Delete {} Section of the Query should be A instead of ?A and B instead of ?B, now it should work. By IF Exists I mean, that it might be possible that the graph I have, has only the A and not the B node. I used to have only A, then the query to delete A and B didn't work. Is it possible to "ask" the graph first if a certain node exist? But you did mention that delete only deletes a statement that exists.